# Why Minitest (Rails 4.2) failed when I add a key/value column (Hstore) in a fixture definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, fixtures, ruby-on-rails-4.2, hstore

I'm using rails 4.2, minitest 5.11.3, and minitest-rails 2.2.1

My test class has some problem when I want to exploit hstore field from postgresql into fixture.

Here my test class **WelcomeMailerTest** when running test is ok:

```
require 'test_helper'
class WelcomeMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  describe 'user_mail_test' do
    let(:user) {users(:anthony)}
    let(:email) {WelcomeMailer.user(user.id)}

    def test_email_to
        assert_equal [user.email], email.to
    end
  end
end
```

My fixture user in the **users.yml** file:

```
anthony:
  username: anthony-mattiocco 
  first_name: Anthony
  last_name: Mattiocco 
  email: user-1@afrikrea.dev
  token: token
  slug: antho
```

When I use a new fixture coutries.yml with key/value field (hstore), the test failed.

Here my new fixture **coutries.yml** :

```
us:
  alpha2: US 
  slugs: <%= {:slug_en => 'test'}.to_yaml.inspect %>
  nationality: 'American'
  currency: 'USD'
```

and my updated **WelcomeMailerTest** class :

```
require 'test_helper'

class WelcomeMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  describe 'user_mail_test' do
    let(:country) {countries(:us)}
    puts("countries : " + country.inspect)
    let(:user) {users(:anthony)}
    let(:email) {WelcomeMailer.user(user.id)}

    def test_email_to
        assert_equal [user.email], email.to
    end
  end
end
```

When I execute :

```
rake test
```

I got the following error :

> Error:
>   user_mail_test#test_email_to:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  **Syntax error near ':'** at position 4
>   LINE 1: ..., "currency", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('US', **'---**
>                                                                      **^**
>   : INSERT INTO "countries" ("alpha2", "slugs", "nationality", "currency", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('US', **'---
>   :slug_en: test**
>   ', 'American', 'USD', '2019-11-14 23:02:06', '2019-11-14 23:02:06')

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: That's not an HSTORE value, that's a YAML serialized document. Can you reproduce this in newer versions of Rails, like 5.2 or 6.0? It may be that support for HSTORE in 4.2 was somewhat lacking, as that's a fairly old version of Rails and is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks tadman for your answer. But for now I have to use this specific rails version. Before I've tried factories and it was ok. But here as you said it's about YAML serialized document. Maybe by updating one specific gem could be a first  workaround before to update rails version.

Comment: Does your model declare that column as `serialized`? The fixtures subsystem in older versions of Rails is pretty limited. You may want to try and use something like [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) instead of fixtures.

Comment: Thanks Tadman, it's my current alternative for the moment, until I update my Rails version.

Comment: You may want to skip the `HSTORE` and use a standard `LONGTEXT` column instead as that will accept YAML data and work with the fixtures system. Later you could migrate to a proper HSTORE when your Rails is on board with it.